# MSSQL 2012 view faster after executing "alter"

Tags: sql-server, sql-view, sqlperformance

I have a situation/context where a specific view takes 120sec before returning a result. When doing a simple ALTER (or drop/create) the view takes 1 to 2 seconds. How is this possible and how can we fix this - as we have no dedicated DBA that can help us out. Making indexed views is not an option due to linked server setup we have (MSSQL Server 2012 complains about that).

Below is information on the setup.

**TL;DR** View_MAIN takes 120 secs after a certain amount of time. When we execute an ALTER view on View_X, View_Y and View_MAIN without changing anything the performance is normal again to 1 to 2 seconds.

---

**View_MAIN**

```
SELECT 
   column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM View_X

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM View_Y
```

**View_X**

```
SELECT
   LTRIM(RTRIM(table1.a)) as column1,
   table2.b COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as column2,
   table1.c as column3,
   CAST(table3.d AS DATETIME) as column4,
   'XXXXXX' as column5
FROM
   [linkedserver01].[DATABASE_IDN].[dbo].[dataForX] table1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_INFM] as table2
   ON table2.id = table1.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_PIK] as table3
   ON table3.id = table1.id
```

**View_Y**

```
SELECT
   LTRIM(RTRIM(table1.a)) as column1,
   table2.b COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as column2,
   table1.c as column3,
   CAST(table3.d AS DATETIME) as column4,
   'YYYYY' as column5
FROM
   [linkedserver01].[DATABASE_IDN].[dbo].[dataForY] table1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_INFM] as table2
   ON table2.id = table1.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_PIK] as table3
   ON table3.id = table1.id
```

Comment: What are the queries against View_Main?   I suspect you have two queries that are using the same plan.  So when you fix the current query you will have another one slow down later (it just hasn't happened yet).  I added comments below to the first proposed Answer (by podiluska).

Comment: SQL Server is build a good plan for the first query but it isn't a good plan for second query.   If this is the problem then Temp fix is to use Plan Guides to optimize for one query.  Larger fix is to parameterize the two queries to make them different.  Plans are stored via literal text.  Find the PLAN in use to help figure out the problem.   ALTER VIEW resets the plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By altering, or recreating, the view, you will be clearing the cached execution plan that exists for this, and recreating it based on the current set of data.

You can achieve the same effect by executing `sp_recompile 'View_Main'`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx

Looking at the actual execution plan for the query should be your starting point to determine why it is running slowly (in SSMS, on the Query menu)

Comment: Thanks. This looks indeed valid, we have no control over the data in the linkedservers, and when they change (see your link "recompiling execution plans") the execution plan could indeed become invalid for the new situation. Would calling, as suggested "An explicit call to sp_recompile", be a solution, and do this weekly as "maintenance", or is that a dirty solution?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe executing sp_recompile is not a "dirty solution" - especially if it solves your problem. The appropriate frequency is dependent on your situation, and how often this slowing occurs - perhaps dependent on a change to one of the data sets.

Comment: Thanks, what about @Raoul-Sebastian 's suggestion to first stage the data and get the linked servers out of the way (given that we need to refresh that staged data a number of times a day then to make sure the data is "live" and "fresh" enough for the end-users using it)?
I'd rather use that "staging" as a last resort - considering that it means more code + maintenance as well when sth changes on the other side, not?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe Eliminating the linked server may remove some of the issues, but it may introduce other problems, depending on your circumstances, and the nature of the data and its usage.

Comment: We will try neogtiating on putting an index on [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_INFM].id as that's an in house developed system fed by Microsoft FIM. That .id =not the primary key, and in the performance plan we saw that it indeed took some time there.. So it might work if we can put and index there. As well as also run a schedueled sp_recompile. Will keep you up to date. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with a single Plan being able to answer two queries.  The first query comes in and sets the Plan.  The second query comes in and tries to use the plan created by the first - but it is inappropriate for second query.

Comment: When you recompile the VIEW the Plan is deleted.  So then Query Two comes in first and defines the plan - which is a good plan.   Plan Guides can help resolve the issue until you can Parameterize the offending queries.  SQL Server will then be able to tell them apart and build two plans.

Comment: @ripvlan if I understand you correctly, you're saying that query two is the second in the nested view (after the union all), or are you referring to just queries being fired to View_MAIN? Can you also explain me (#noob - I know) what "Plan Guides" are, or point me somewhere to? Thanks!

Comment: New ideas came to me overnight.   Could be stats gone bad.   New approach. Figure out the problem.  Next time it misbehaves grab the query plan. Show plan Xml.   Or execute from SSMS with Show Actual Plan enabled.

Comment: To clarify my original Guess. There are two queries against Main from your app. One looks like Select From Main where someCol=xyz. And the other will be Select From Main where someCol > abc.  Or <>   Very different. SQL is using the same plan for both.

Comment: But first. When does it go bad. It was working. Then not working. Any idea what happened in between?  Queries don't just go bad. Something changed. Large data insert. Maint job. Different queries that look similar but aren't. One returns 5 rows the other 10,000.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to eliminate the linked servers and load the data needed in your analytic database or wherever you need it, on a schedule that fits your needs.
Other than that, I can only guess that somebody or some application queries the view and generates a false execution plan. It could be that it totally under- or overestimates the resultset. You can try

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

before querying the view or you could try the [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) Recompile if really nothing else helps or better yet option fast. If you can estimate the number of rows the view usually returns, let's say its 50.000 rows, you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM View_MAIN OPTION (FAST 50000);
```

EDIT:

Why I suggest to get rid of linked servers:

1. You lack the general db logging, statistics, execution plans and so on.
2. Once you don’t have dbo or similar permissions, you won't be able to use stats, leading to bad performance across linked server connections.
3. You mostly get the full results and the data joining is organized afterwards. So try to join the smallest possible resultset from the remote server.
4. You don't know if your query was deadlocked on the target server, if you don't have access to it.

If you are forced to use linked servers consider [OPENQUERY](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa276848(v=sql.80).aspx). That way the aggregations will be perfomed on your SQL server.

Comment: Considering the demand is "live data" as fast as possible, we neglected to build such a data gathering first - but it seems like this will be the better option, every x-times per day to refresh and query from there. Essentially doing a "dump" and staging data before querying and using it for reporting you suggest?

Comment: Take a look at [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937(v=sql.120).aspx). Basically you would "trigger" an ETL process every time any of your source data changes and refresh your reporting table.

Comment: Change Data Capture is only available in the Enterprise edition. I'm guessing that you wouldn't have that version and not have a dedicated DBA.

Comment: We don't have a dedicated dba, but do have the EEdition. Will first try neogtiating on putting an index on [linkedserver02].[DATABASE_INFM].id as that's an in house developed system fed by Microsoft FIM. That .id =not the primary key, and in the performance plan we saw that it indeed took some time there.. So it might work if we can put and index there. As well as also run a schedueled sp_recompile. Will keep you up to date. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It used to be enterprise only on 2008R2, I am not sure for 2012 and 2014, but you could be right.